# subqueries with different groupings in db2 not returning division results correctly

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I absolutely can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My data here is close but my V2 and V3 subqueries are not returning the correct data and I think it's based on the fact that I'm trying to divide by groupings on a SUM and it feels like it's using the same strCount number across the board.

The query:

```
WITH T (employee, manager, GROUP, detail1, detail2, strCount, QUANT, LAST_SHIP_DATE) AS (
VALUES  (21177, 165, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (19445, 182, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (20949, 340, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 2, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (21347, 353, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (23068, 353, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (17195, 353, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 6, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (23040, 353, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (5620,  380, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 4, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (23009, 380, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 3, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (13529, 390, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (22706, 394, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (17049, 394, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 4, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (17879, 397, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (21320, 445, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY),
        (21231, 457, 4867, 2878, 29, 1, 1, CURRENT DATE - 10 DAY)
)
SELECT T.employee, T.manager, T.GROUP, T.detail1, T.detail2, T.strCount, T.QUANT
, COALESCE(T1.V1, 0) V1, COALESCE(T2.V2, 0) V2, COALESCE(T3.V3, 0) V3
FROM T
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT employee, GROUP, detail1, detail2, SUM(QUANT)/SUM(strCount)*12 V1
FROM T
WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
GROUP BY employee, GROUP, detail1, detail2,strCount
) T1 ON T1.employee=T.employee AND T1.GROUP=T.GROUP AND T1.detail1=T.detail1 AND T1.detail2=T.detail2 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT manager, GROUP, detail1, detail2, SUM(QUANT)/SUM(strCount)*12 V2
FROM T
WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
GROUP BY manager, GROUP, detail1, detail2,strCount
) T2 ON T2.manager=T.manager AND T2.GROUP=T.GROUP AND T2.detail1=T.detail1 AND T2.detail2=T.detail2
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT GROUP, detail1, detail2, SUM(QUANT)/SUM(strCount)*12 V3
FROM T
WHERE last_ship_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
GROUP BY GROUP, detail1, detail2,strCount
) T3 ON T3.GROUP=T.GROUP AND T3.detail1=T.detail1 AND T3.detail2=T.detail2;
```

This gives me

```
employee | manager | group | detail1 | detail2 | strCount | quant | V1 | V2 | V3
================================================================================
21177    | 165     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 12
19445    | 182     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 12
20949    | 340     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 2     | 24 | 24 | 12
21347    | 353     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 24 | 12
23068    | 353     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 24 | 12
17195    | 353     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 6     | 72 | 24 | 12
23040    | 353     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 24 | 12
5620     | 380     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 4     | 48 | 36 | 12
23009    | 380     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 3     | 36 | 36 | 12
13529    | 390     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 12
22706    | 394     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 24 | 12
17049    | 394     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 4     | 48 | 24 | 12
17879    | 397     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 12
21320    | 445     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 12
21231    | 457     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 12
```

But Expecting:

```
employee | manager | group | detail1 | detail2 | strCount | quant | V1 | V2 | V3
==================================================================================
21177    | 165     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 22.4
19445    | 182     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 22.4
20949    | 340     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 2     | 24 | 24 | 22.4
21347    | 353     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 27 | 22.4
23068    | 353     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 27 | 22.4
17195    | 353     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 6     | 72 | 27 | 22.4
23040    | 353     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 27 | 22.4
5620     | 380     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 4     | 48 | 42 | 22.4
23009    | 380     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 3     | 36 | 42 | 22.4
13529    | 390     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 22.4
22706    | 394     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 30 | 22.4
17049    | 394     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 4     | 48 | 30 | 22.4
17879    | 397     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 22.4
21320    | 445     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 22.4
21231    | 457     | 4867  | 2878    | 29      | 1        | 1     | 12 | 12 | 22.4
```

How can I properly alter this so that the groupings of employee, manager and total reflect the grouped sum of strCount as well as the grouped sum of quant?

Update:

The logic here is this

I want to get this same number of rows with the qualifying information as it is now, but my V1, V2 and V3 columns should be like this:

V1: The sum of quantity for the grouping of employee/group/detail1/detail2 divided by the sum of the strCount of the same grouping (this is currently returning correctly)

V2: The sum of quantity for the grouping of manager/group/detail1/detail2 divided by the sum of the strCount by the same grouping

V3: The sum of total quantity for the group/detail1/detail2 divided by the sum of the total strCount by the same grouping

Comment: You haven't done much to explain the logic of the query, or to point out what might be going on with the current and expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen does my update help to clarify at all?

Answer (score 0):

`INT/INT = INT` in DB2, i.e. 3/2 = 1, and not 1.5

Use `decfloat(SUM(QUANT))/SUM(strCount)*12` or `dec(SUM(QUANT), 28)/SUM(strCount)*12`

And you don't need to group by `strCount` since you use aggregate function on it, unless you really need to include this column into grouping due to some application logic.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe I didn't realize that. I obviously have a lot to learn still with DB2. Let me apply this real quick